# BufferOverrun :codesonar warning

Tags: c++

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::string first_arg = argv[1];
    std:: string sec_arg = argv[2];
}
```

Buffer Overrun help
This code reads past the end of the buffer pointed to by argv.
The first byte read is at offset 8 from the beginning of the buffer pointed to by argv.
The offset exceeds the capacity.
The capacity of the buffer pointed to by argv, in bytes, is equal to 8.

Comment: Show the command line used to invoke your program.  You might want to check you actually have `argc >= 3`

Comment: Code Sonar is checking what happens if your program isn't passed any arguments and, as expected, there are problems. If you don't know what the product is good for or what it does, there's probably no point in your purchasing it (there's no list price, but it's "starting at $4,000 USD for small projects", according to one site) unless spending money is your hobby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CodeSonar warns that there can be a buffer overrun as your program could be called with <2 arguments. If you check that argc>2 before you access argv, then this warning will go away:

```
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    if (argc>2)
    {
            std::string first_arg = argv[1];
            std::string sec_arg = argv[2];
    }
    return 0;
}
```